# Postgresql regexp_replace negative lookahead not working

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to replace street with st only if street isn't followed by any alphabet. Replacement is allowed if after street EITHER there is non-alphabet character OR end of string.

I am trying to achieve this in Postgresql 9.5 regex_replace function. Sample query i wrote:

`select regexp_replace('super streetcom','street(?!=[a-z])','st');`

street here shouldn't have been replaced by st since street is followed by 'c'. So the expected output is 'super streetcom' but the output i am getting is 'super stcom'.

Any help for why i am getting the unexpected output and what can be the right way to achieve the intended result.

Comment: Are you sure `(?!=pattern)` is the correct negative lookahead syntax in postgresql? Usualy it is just `(?!pattern)`

Comment: Ohhh.. Found my mistake. negative lookahead should have been (?!pattern). Thanks @SebastianProske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**lookahead construct**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) looks like `(?!...)`, all what follows `?!` is a lookahead pattern that the engine will try to match, and once found, the match will be failed.

It seems you need to match a whole word `street`. Use `\y`, a word boundary:

```
select regexp_replace('super streetcom street','\ystreet\y','st');
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/NBAR13679)

[image]

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES):

> `\y`  matches only at the beginning or end of a word

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a syntax issue. Try: `?!` instead of `?!=` .
e.g.

```
select regexp_replace('super street','street(?![a-z])','st');
```

will return

```
super st
```